# jQuery Date and TimePicker

Tags: jquery, datetime, datetimepicker

I am trying to use the date and time picker located at

http://razum.si/jQuery-calendar/TimeCalendar.html

However this picker works only if the jquery-ui.js is not included. It looks like it conflicts with something with the base jquery-ui.js.

The jquery core api is required.

Any insight would be helpful.

thanks in advance.

The code is

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-calendar.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-calendar.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="styles.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function (){ 
            $("#calendar1").calendar();

        });
    //]]>
    </script>
```

and the code to bring the popup on focusing on input field is

```
 <input type="text" id="calendar1" class="calendarFocus"/>
```

The script can be seen by looking into the source of the page, for which link is given above. (I am not able to post more links here, as stack overflow is not allowing it).

Comment: post your code (script includes and JS)

Comment: Finally I wrote my own date and time picker which uses the basic jquery calendar and uses drop downs for time picker and managed the things with scripts

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this plugin.  But I override jQuery UI's autocomplete with the [Pengoworks one](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm) by placing the script call after the UI call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing your code,

However if u continue to have problems with this date picker.. I have always used [THIS](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/dateinput/index.html)
 one, really easy and looks great too.

Comment: This is just a date picker and not a date and time picker. I am looking for a date and time picker.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download the jquery UI with only the modules that you need. (So without the datepicker).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. However I am keeping this option as last resort.

Comment: Maybe you can try firebug to see what goes wrong. I guess that jquery is extended 2 times with the same name or something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean. You use jQuery in you page and you want to use the razum timecalender, but that one clashes with jquery?

Maybe use the jQuery UI version? Probably easier to implement because you already have jQuery. [see here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Comment: It clashes with the jquery ui version. The link that you are suggesting is just a date picker and not a date and time picker